# Mailer in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, apartment-gem

I am migrating an ROR3 application to ROR4. And I am very new to this and I am learning along with the migration.
I got stuck in the first step it self
I am getting an error

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in ClientsController#create
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtq6
```

Here is my configuration in development.rb.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
          :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
          :port                 => 587,
          :domain               => "gmail.com",
          :user_name            => Rails.application.secrets.email_address,
          :password             => Rails.application.secrets.email_password,
          :authentication       => "plain",
          :enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

The place where I am getting the error is at

> @client.save.

```
 Apartment::Tenant.create(@client.subdomain)
      Apartment::Tenant.switch(@client.subdomain)
      @client.save
      redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @client.subdomain)
    else
      render action: 'new'
```

Can anyone help who is working on ROR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue, be sure to take a look at your `gmail` account security settings and enable `"Access for less secure apps" from www.google.com/settings/security."`

Comment: Man you are a life save. Can you post it as the answer so that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat my pleasure, it is already answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :user_name => "your mail",
     :password => "your password",
     :authentication => :plain,
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```